# Round a POSIX date and time (posixct) to a date relative to a timezone

Tags: r, date, rounding, posixct

I want to round a POSIXct down to the day, relative to a specific timezone.

If I try

```
round(as.POSIXct("2013-03-05 23:00:00 EST"), "day")
```

It returns

```
2013-03-06
```

Which makes sense, in that when it's 23:00:00 EST on 2013-03-05 in EST5EDT, it's already 2013-03-06 in UTC. Logically, what I want to do is:

```
round(as.POSIXct("2013-03-05 23:00:00 EST"), "day", tz="EST5EDT")
```

That is, "round this date and time to the nearest day, relative to the EST5EDT time zone". Unfortunately, *round* doesn't take a time zone parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`round` will round to the next day once it's past midday, which is why I think you are seeing 2013-03-06. I also have to explicitly set the `tz` argument in the call to `as.POSIXct`

Observe:

```
round( as.POSIXct("2013-03-05 11:00:00" , tz = "EST" ), "day" )
[1] "2013-03-05 EST"
```

And then once it passes noon:

```
round( as.POSIXct("2013-03-05 12:00:00" , tz = "EST" ), "day" )
[1] "2013-03-06 EST"
```

A call to `format` extracts the day as a character string without the tz argument. So you can get your original result without the timezone

```
format( round( as.POSIXct("2013-03-05 12:00:00" , tz = "EST" ), "day" ) )
[1] "2013-03-06"
```

If you want to *round* any time on that day to that day perhaps what you want instead is `trunc`?

```
format(trunc( as.POSIXct("2013-03-05 12:00:00" , tz = "EST" ), "day" ))
[1] "2013-03-05"
```