# Extracting data from one data set, using another in r

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to extract data from one data set (contains water quality data -- chlorophyll, dissolved oxygen, temp, etc), using information from another data set that contains tidal information (low tide times).

Background: It has recently come to my attention that due to hydrodynamics it will be best to only look at WQ  data points measured at low tide, when I had previously just taken the daily average.

Is there a way I can extract specific WQ data based on if it aligns with date/time of the tidal data??? Caveats -- the times might not match up exactly, WQ data was measured every 15 minutes so I need the closest point(s) to the low tide time.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to give the exact code without knowing the frequency of your tidal data. However, you can take a look at the following links, using which you could match the timestamps on both your datasets by rounding them off to the nearest hour/half hour/quarter hour (as the case may be):

1. [rounding times to the nearest hour in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444242/rounding-times-to-the-nearest-hour-in-r)
2. [Rounding time to nearest quarter hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862056/rounding-time-to-nearest-quarter-hour)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please try adding significant bits of info or code from the links just in case they get broken in the future